# Is it a good idea to assign a std::string_view type in constructor?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-view

I understand that using `std::string_view` is better than `std::string` because it allows `const char*` and `std::string` values to be passed without needing a `std::string` object to be created.
Also i understand the it provides a ReadOnly access

However, i was wondering if it is a good practice to define a public `std:string_view` variable and update it through the class constructor.

i.e:
What is the difference between `test1` and `test2`, assuming `test1` or `test2` is defined in a library class which can be instantiated by different clients.

```
class test1{
public:
 std::string_view name_;
 
 test1 (std::string_view name): name_ {name} {};
 void print() {
     cout<<"test1 "<<name_<<endl;
 }
};

class test2{
public:
 std::string name_;
 
 test2 (std::string_view name): name_ {name} {};
 void print() {
     cout<<"test2 "<<name_<<endl;
 }

};
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with `string_view` is that it's only good for as long as the underlying string hasn't been invalidated. The `test1` version means that the underlying string has to remain valid for the entire lifespan of a `test1` object.

Comment: The tragedy of `std::string_view` is that it's not universal. E.g. if you're going to copy it into a string (as in snippet 2), you should actually be passing `std::string` and then `std::move`ing it to avoid an extra copy. (Also you can't check if `std::string_view` is null-terminated, which is also problematic in some other cases.)

Comment: This is a good usecase for [`[[clang::lifetimebound]]`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#lifetimebound) https://godbolt.org/z/95asa963s

Comment: I really wouldn't do `test1`, for reasons given above in the comments.  The idea behind `std::string_view` is that you can pass it around as a lightweight object with a strictly limited (and well-defined) lifetime.  Storing it in a member variable is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

While it's not wrong as such, it's potentially unsafe. It's extremely important for the user of the class to understand that the member will remain valid only as long as the pointed string's lifetime, which may be shorter than that of the object. It should be both documented clearly, and the name of the class should reflect its referential nature. Some examples are suffixes such as `_view` or `_ref`.

The class `test1` won't be useful in such cases where the lifetime must be longer than that of the pointed string. This consideration is same as when using a member of type `const char*`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai But it shouldn't be used for that. Especially if you pass that pointer through the constructor.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Well it *can*... but also shouldn't be used for that :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat touche squared. I take back all I wrote

Comment: sometimes I say stupid things, and to avoid ppl starting to believe that I am a bot I make a lot of tpyos ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are important differences.

1. Lifetime of the underlying data is different:

   ```
    Test1 createTest1() {
       std::string tempName = "temporary";
       return Test1(tempName);
    }
    // here name_ will become a dangling reference, this is UB
    test1 a = createTest1();
   ```

   No such problem will happen in case of test2.
2. `std::string` will allocate data which is greater overhead over a version with `string_view`.
3. You cannot modify `string_view`, its immutable (but it might change in c++23)
4. Version with `std::string` requires more memory that the version with `std::string_view`. `std::string` even when in SSO mode requires, some array of bytes to store small strings, and this array is usually a minimal size of `std::string`.
5. The choice of `test1` vs `test2` can greatly depend on how your application is structured, if you mostly pass `string_view`-s then use `test1`, otherwise if you use `std::string` then use `test2`.
6. `std::string` supports more operations than `std::string_view`.